# How to replicate Angular Material Form Field Background Color

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, angular-material, css-selectors

Task is to make Angular Material form field the very slight gray color with the curved top edges as shown on the Material page (https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples#form-field-overview). Currently the form field background appears to have no color.  I need to override whatever settings there are in the Material package in another custom CSS document.

When I examined the example in developer tools it looks like there is a styles sheet it looks like there is a div in there with a class named "mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay". Looked into that and there is a style sheet for the class that looks like it is part of Angular Material. Am I able to make a custom version of this file to override the default?

I believe the class that I need to change is ".mat-form-field-infix" so I changed it to this just to verify:

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
  line-height: initial;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

Test Result

[image]

Desired Result

I did change the color in the right place, however it does not look like it does in the example linked above from the Material page where it is very light grey with the curved edges.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the APIs of each tag associated inside the `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>` in app.module.ts file.